# React JS unique key prop

Tags: reactjs, key, warnings

Please, look at this small part of code from my react component.

```
render() {
    // below line makes sure that each category is unique
    const categories = this.getUniqueCategories(this.props.items);
    const TRs = categories.map(category => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <tr key={category}>
            <td colSpan="2">{category}</td>
          </tr>
          <ProductRow items={this.props.items} category={category} />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });
    return TRs;
  }
```

Why this render method gives warning of unique "key" prop? Please, note that `ProductRow` component consists of `tr` tags and each of them has unique `item.id` key. So, no problem in there.

My data:

```
const items = [
      {
        id: "1",
        category: "Sporting Goods",
        price: "$49.99",
        stocked: true,
        name: "Football"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        category: "Sporting Goods",
        price: "$9.99",
        stocked: true,
        name: "Baseball"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        category: "Sporting Goods",
        price: "$29.99",
        stocked: false,
        name: "Basketball"
      },
      {
        id: "4",
        category: "Electronics",
        price: "$99.99",
        stocked: true,
        name: "iPod Touch"
      },
      {
        id: "5",
        category: "Electronics",
        price: "$399.99",
        stocked: false,
        name: "iPhone 5"
      },
      {
        id: "6",
        category: "Electronics",
        price: "$199.99",
        stocked: true,
        name: "Nexus 7"
      }
    ];
```

Comment: How does the data look like ? Also how does the ProductRow component look like. That might also need a unique key.

Comment: Shot in the dark I might be wrong but I had the same issue the other day. I moved the key to the very top most container within the `map` and the error went away. However, your container is within the Fragment so I would try wrapping a div and appending a key there to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @Sushanth--added sample

Comment: Each child of a fragment needs a key

Comment: @Li357 should I add key to `ProductRow`? I tried to `key={category}` for `ProductRow`, but warning didn't disappear.

Comment: @ElginCahangirov Those keys aren't unique. `ProductRow` needs a different key than the value of `category`...

Comment: @Li357 `category` is unique. Please, see comment line after `render`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put key={category} on fragment tag

Comment: My pleasure mate :)

Comment: can I ask you another simple question?

Comment: Sure :) let's go w with another one

Comment: "All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props." My question is about this line. For example consider this component: "function SomeComponent(props): \n let items = props.items \n items = items.filter(...)". Does this code violates above statement?

Comment: Regarding pure function it shouldn't modify it's parameters or context sorrounding it and it should return same value for same params. In that case you are not modifying props so there is no violation of pure function related rules.

Comment: By the way `category.id` would be a better idea